Getting a computed object in the parent from a child component?
I have an object in a child component, something like:
const obj = computed(() => ({
  abc: someField.value,
  xyz: anotherField.value,
}));

In the parent I want to get this object, how can I do this?

You can watch its changes then emit it to the parent

Consider explaining your case. It's more like the comment above suggests rather than the answer shows with a ref. It's possible to do the latter, but it has to be reasoned, which it rarely is.

Using watch:
In the child component:
const emit = defineEmits(['obj-changed']);

watch(
  () => obj.value,
  (val) => emit('obj-changed', val),
  { immediate: true }
);

In the parent component:
<child-component @obj-changed="handleObjChanged" />

const handleObjChanged = (val) => console.log(val);

Using defineExpose:
In the child componenet:
defineExpose({ obj });

In the parent component:
<child-component ref="child" />

const child = ref();

And finally access it using:
child.value?.obj

